# Railroad questline: House Divided - no next mission from Father?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm doing a playthrough with the Railroad. "Keep working with Father" is a main quest objective for now, and during that you go through the usual institute steps: Libertalia, etc.

Problem: After doing "House Divided", there is no next quest. Father only gives you a token response, and the Railroad only has PAM missions.

Either the PAM missions must be done, or the mission trail has gone stale due to a bug. Anyone have insight on this?

Note: Because my character has low charisma, I finished House Divided by letting the synth gorillas out, then killed the gorillas. One of the Institute people are now talking to his invisible friend about the gorillas that now no longer exist.

I am playing on the PS4.

Am I stuck in bugland or is there another way to move quests forward?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already completed A House Divided, the next main quest you can tackle is [Mass Fusion](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_Fusion).

If Father has no new dialogue, you need to speak with Dr. Allie Filmore. If you have already spoken to Dr. Filmore, then you can try going to Mass Fusion building. If you get the prompt that you will become a permanent enemy of The Brotherhood of Steel, then you are on the right track.

And since you are doing a Railroad play through, completing Mass Fusion on The Institute side and becoming an enemy of The Brotherhood of Steel is required to maintain your cover.

Comment: Ok, I'm def an enemy of the BOS. I'll try those other things to ensure those checks were made. I'll tick answer once I know it works. Thank you.

Comment: Note: if choosing to side with either of the Institute, the Railroad or BoS, you will eventually become permanent enemy with the other two. And you will also become hostile to the faction-specific NPC companion of that faction: X6, Deacon or Danse (but get to keep any perks you got for maximizing friendship/romance with them).